# Converting a date to a number for a primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to input a number of values to a dimension table that I created but I keep getting the following error -

```
ORA-06512: at line 2
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
No Erro
```

I am trying to convert the input date from format DD/MM/YYYY to a number that can then act as the primary key for the dimension table. It seems to be in the wrong format. Can anyone shed some light on it

```
  DECLARE
      vstartDate number(10):= to_number(to_char('&StartDate','DDMMYYYY')); 
      vendDate number(10) := to_number(to_Char('&EndDate','DD/MM/YYYY'));
      vdate_key number(10) not null:= to_number(to_Char(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need the primary key as a number; couldn't you keep it as a date instead?

Regardless, the issue is that you've forgotten to convert the string you're passing into a date before then passing it back as a number. At the moment, you're attempting to convert a string to a string and then making sure it's got forward slashes in, before trying to convert it to a number. Numbers can't contain forward slashes!

Here's what I think you're after:

```
DECLARE
  vstartDate number(10):= to_number(to_char(to_date('&StartDate','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YYYYMMDD')); 
  vendDate number(10) := to_number(to_char(to_date('&EndDate','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YYYYMMDD'));
  vdate_key number(10) not null := to_number(to_Char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD'));
```

Note that I've changed the format of the output number to YYYYMMDD, as this is easier to sort by. I'd still rather store the date as a date, however!